# How do I create a table model in SQL?

Tags: sql, performance

Let's say I've 3 tables: `enterprise, users, houses`.

Everyone needs an address. What should I do?

- Create a table address for everyone?
- Create one unique table address?

Assuming that the first is "more" correct (cache, fragmentation, size, ...), how should I write it in plain SQL?

How do I create a "model" of the table address, and use it in custom tables (e.g. enterprise_address)?
* So when I change one field in the model, it gets replicated.

Comment: Start with your business requirements and design a database to satisfy them.  Worry about the rest later.

Comment: @DanBracuk I really agree with you.  "Premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Comment: @user1101 There are some really good answers below. Please feel free to close out your question by accepting an answer.

Comment: @zedfoxus Not really. I was stating points, not questioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer to postgresql: use `INHERITS`

e.g. `CREATE TABLE name () INHERITS (table_model)`

Thank you all for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you need every user to have an address. You have multiple ways to solve it.

**Handle it in UI**

- Your users table will be just information about users (on address info here)
- Create addresses table with addressid as primary key
- Create many-to-many table/junction table called user_addresses that brings userid and addressid together
- Ensure that your UI mandates address for each user

Tables

```
create table addresses (addressid int not null PK, line1, line2, city ...);
create table users (userid int not null PK, username, ...);
create table user_addresses (user_addressid int, userid int, addressid int, UK userid + addressid, FK to users, FK to addresses);
```

This allows a user to have multiple addresses. You have the flexibility of marking which one is primary.

**Handle it in DB (and UI)**

```
create table addresses (addressid int not null PK, ....);
create table users (userid int not null PK, username varchar(20), ..., addressid int not null, FK to addresses);
```

This allows one address per user.

and handle it also on the UI to ensure that address is supplied. Enter address into addresses first and then into users (make it an atomic process; use transactions!)

You can start with one these methods and analyze what your business needs are. Work with your DBA, if you have one, to see what their experience says about the business and previous DB designs similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

Just from the three given tables I would assume that address is something you would want to put in either Houses or Users.

Depending on how much detail you want to keep track of in the Address it could be work making a separate table but there are a number of ways to go about this and the correct method depends solely on what you are trying to achieve.

Without knowing any of the required information all I can really advise is that you should aim to store the addresses as unique values. Once you have this you can assign each address to any other table you wish using a Foreign Key.

If you want to store multiple fields for the address then you will require a seperate table, if a single field will do then it could just as easily be added to the person or houses table.

One thing that would make a major difference to which way you would want to do this is the relationship between address and your other entities. For example if a user can have many addresses then you cant make it a part of the user table, and if an address can have multiple users assigned to it then it cant use a FK to represent its relationship to the users table.

One way you can do this is to make a relational table. So you make addresses and users seperate tables then have another table with just an id(pk) and 2 fks linking it to each of the other tables. This way you can have a many to many relationship if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

First question: how many addresses per enterprise/user/house? If there are multiple addresses per entity, that leads you to want a separate address table, possibly with an address type.

Examples of multiple address situations:

- Multiple locations
- Ship-to addresses
- Physical vs. PO Box

If you are going to assert that an entity can only have one address, then you probably prefer making the address part of the entity row, for simplicity. However, there can be reasons not to do that; for example, table width (number of columns in the table).

If you have multiple addresses per entity, typically you will use a foreign key. The entity should have an abstract key: some kind of ID. This will either be an integer or, in SQL Server, it could be a uniqueidentifier. The entity ID will be part of the key for the address.